# IE: Undocumented "cache" attribute defined for input elements?

Tags: javascript, dom, internet-explorer, custom-attribute, undocumented-behavior

I've stumpled upon a strange behavior in IE(6/7/8) that drives me nuts. Given the following markup:

```
<input type="text" value="foo" class="bar" cache="yes" send="no" />
```

Please note that the `cache` attribute is set to `yes`. However IE somehow manages to change the attributes value to `cache="cache"` when rendering the DOM.

So, I wonder, is there an undocumented feature that I'm not aware of? I've googled about an hour now but couldn't find any info on this (not even on MSDN).

**NOTE**
I'm aware that adding custom attributes is non-standard compliant and that boolean attributes should be noted as `attribute="attribute"`. Nevertheless I have to cope with these as they were introduced long before I joined the team. These custom attributes are used in conjunction with javascript to provide a more user friendly approach to form handling (and it works out quite well with Firefox/Safari/Opera/Chrome).

I know that I could simply convert these custom attributes to x-data attributes that will be introduced with HTML5 but that would take me several hours of extra work - sigh.

Hope, I made myself clear.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

For ages, it has been that boolean attributes are preferrably written as `<input type="checkbox" checked="checked"/>` etc. This is because in the dinosaur age, you were supposed to only write `<input type="checkbox" checked/>` and assigning the same value as the property name broke the fewest legacy browsers, while still making the markup XML-compliant.

Comment: As i wrote, I'm aware of this legacy issue. The thing is IE won't break the "send" attribute.

Comment: If you say that, I recommend you rephrase, because I have read your question twice more now and still can't see where you say that. How do you read the attribute value?

Comment: You're right, I didn't mention it explicitly - I'll edit the post.